# No screenshots are captured by serenity after test run

Tags: selenium, junit, bdd, serenity-bdd

I have serenity.properties file with such configurations:

```
serenity.take.screenshots = BEFORE_AND_AFTER_EACH_STEP
webdriver.driver = "chrome"
```

Also I have PageObjects, Steps layer and Tests module

My Gradle build file looks like:

```
group 'com.am'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'net.serenity-bdd.aggregator'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("net.serenity-bdd:serenity-gradle-plugin:1.4.0")
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:1.4.0'
    compile 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-junit:1.4.0'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.0'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.7'
    compile group: 'net.serenity-bdd', name: 'serenity-rest-assured', version: '1.4.0'
    compile group: 'org.jsoup', name: 'jsoup', version: '1.8.3'
    compile 'ru.yandex.qatools.htmlelements:htmlelements-all:1.17'
}

gradle.startParameter.continueOnFailure = true
```

When I run tests with simple command

```
gradle clean test aggregate
```

Report is generated but without any screenshots.

My report looks like:

[generated report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tMsh.png)

Could anybody please give an advice where am I wrong?
I think it's some simple one but I can't understand where...
In all manuals it says that serenity makes screenshots by default but I don't have any.

Comment: Also I run tests by @RunWith(SerenityRunner.class)

Comment: Can you look at the json files that are generated for report rendering ? That might give you an insight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is solved. Driver should be managed by Serenity but I used to create my own instance of a driver.

Resolution:
1. add Managed tag to tests

```
@Managed
WebDriver driver;
```

2. remove from all places any other driver instances.
3. check that serenity.properties contains (e.g)

   webdriver.driver = chrome
   webdriver.chrome.driver = pathtodriver/chromedriver.exe